# Obtain the folder path

Tags: java, jar

My program has a RMI folder in SRC catalogue. I want to pack the program to JAR. How to obtain the folder path in this catalogue?

Comment: I'm not sure your requirements here are actually clear. Are you packing it in a jar from Java at runtime? Do you just need a build script that will jar it for you when you run it (such as ANT/Maven)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using eclipse then right click on the desired file then click Export..Once clicked you will get option to export as JAR file..Hope this helps..

Comment: Where does the jar comes in export in eclipse ?Could form only the tar or zip

Comment: It probably depends on which version of Eclipse you've installed (J2EE version includes this for example). I don't see any indication of what IDE the OP is using however.

Answer (score 2):

get file path under class path：
for example,there is a file in jar 
    a\a.log 
  you can get absolute path through the following ways:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("a\a.log");
```

if get flow：

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a\a.log");
```

other several ways

1、get the resources of current class

```
MyServlet.class.getResourceAsStream(name)
```

2、get Classpath resource

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)
```

3、how visit in Servle?t   access web application of resources

```
ServletContext context = this.getServletContext(); 
String catalogFileName = context.getInitParameter(“catalogFileName”); 
InputStream is = null; 
BufferedReader catReader = null; 

try { 
is = context.getResourceAsStream(catalogFileName); 
catReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution by obtaining the relative path of `System.getProperty("user.dir")`